# How to limit occurrence of substring in Regular Expression to one?

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
/\A((\{YY\})?[-_]*(\{MM\})?[-_]*(\{DD\})?[-_]*(\{N{4,8}\})|[A-Za-z])*\z/
```

that matches values such as:

```
{YY}-{MM}-{DD}-{NNNN}
```

Is there a way to limit the number of substrings contained within `{N` and `N}` to one, so that the following string would be invalid?

```
{YY}-{MM}-{DD}-{NNNN}-{NNNNNN}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: (1) Regexes are generally hard to read. It would be better for you to explain what each part of your regex does.

Comment: Rather than dumping a regex and making us figure it out, it would be better if you explained what the regex is supposed to match. For example, what's that `[A-Za-z_.#-]` for? And your regex also matches things like `{YY}-{NNNN}{YY}-{NNNN}`; is that intended or not?

Comment: (2) Where are you stuck at? You are able to write such a complex regex, and you ask how to do something much simpler than that.

Comment: replace `(\{N{4,8}\})|[A-Za-z_.#-])*` by `\{N{4,8}\}?` (optional N-sequence) or `\{N{4,8}\}` (single N-sequence)

Comment: @CoronA You'll have to wrap that in parentheses if you want to make it optional.

Comment: @CoronA If you have an answer, write an answer. *Avoid answering questions in comments*.

Comment: @tintin81: you changed the regex such that you problem is not present any more, This regex matches other patterns, but not the invalid one, right?

Comment: No, the regex in my initial post still doesn't work for me. However, I found the solution to my problem -- thanks to your help -- and posted a new answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved my problem with the following regex:

```
/\A([A-Za-z_-]*(\{YY(YY)?\})?[_-]*(\{MM\})?[_-]*(\{DD\})?[_-]*\{N{4,8}\}[A-Za-z_-]*){1}\z/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(\{N{4,8}\})|[A-Za-z_.#-])*
```

The star at the end says: Capture zero OR MORE of this {NNN...N} capturing expression.

```
(\{N{4,8}\})|[A-Za-z_.#-]){,1}
```

The `{,1}` says: maximum 1x previous expression (which is captured by `( )`). Or as Biffen remaked: `?` as short for `{,1}`.

```
/\A((\{YY\})?[-_]*(\{MM\})?[-_]*(\{DD\})?[-_]*(\{N{4,8}\})|[A-Za-z])?\z/
```

So this should capture only `{YY}-{MM}-{DD}-{NNNN}` but not 
`{YY}-{MM}-{DD}-{NNNN}-{NNNNNN}`

Comment: `?` is the shorter and more commonly used version of `{,1}`.

Comment: Mismatched parentheses.

Comment: and this would match `{YY}-{MM}-{DD}-{NNNN}--`

Comment: @CoronA No, it would not.

Comment: @CoronA it would match `{YY}-{MM}-{DD}--` but not `{YY}-{MM}-{DD}-{NNNN}--` (wouldn't match anything containing sth other than end of line after `N}`.